# How to know the reason of failed sign in using Sitefinity OwinContext?

Tags: c#, sitefinity

I use claims to authenticate and based on this documentation [auth user](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/111/for-developers-authenticate-users) I can use OwinContext to sign in. However, unlike SecurityManager.Authenticate OwinContext does not return reason of failed sign in.

```
var owinContext = SystemManager.CurrentHttpContext.Request.GetOwinContext();
var challengeProperties = ChallengeProperties.ForLocalUser(username, password, provider, isPersistent, errorRedirectUrl);
challengeProperties.RedirectUri = successRedirectUrl;

// this call will trigger redirects to the appropriate Identity Provider
owinContext.Authentication.Challenge(challengeProperties, ClaimsManager.CurrentAuthenticationModule.STSAuthenticationType);
```

I need to know the reason of failed sign in. Something like UserLoggingReason in SecurityManager.Authenticate so I can handle the result accordingly.

```
User user;
UserLoggingReason result = SecurityManager.AuthenticateUser(
    provider,
    username,
    password,
    isPersistent,
    out user);

if (result != UserLoggingReason.Success)
{
    SystemManager.CurrentHttpContext.Response.Redirect(errorRedirectUrl, false);
}
else
{
    SystemManager.CurrentHttpContext.Response.Redirect(successRedirectUrl, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at how the Sitefinity widgets, e.g. the LoginForm does this:

https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/blob/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Identity/Mvc/Models/LoginForm/LoginFormModel.cs#L285

You'll probably be interested in the GetReturnUrl implementation:

https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/blob/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Identity/Mvc/Models/LoginForm/LoginFormModel.cs#L486

Comment: Same implementation like in documentation I mentioned.